# Is it possible to retrieve cookies from a website without using android.webkit.WebView?

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

So I have an app, where you have to sign into a service, then you get a session-cookie as a reply if the login was successful. Currently, the login happens in an embedded browser inside an activity (WebView).

The problem, however, is that the customer would rather use the phone's browser to do the login. This is fair enough, but if I log in to the service using the native browser (Chrome), how to i retrieve this cookie and send it to my application? I assume I start an intent, which launches chrome, but how to I, while in chrome, store the cookies from each page, and send this info back to my application?

Is this even possible?

Thanks :)

Comment: you can't. for security reason you cannot access the cookies from another application.

Comment: So this means that I'll be forced to use the embedded browser/WebView in order for the login to work?